# How to change the representation of data in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a SSRS Report.

In the report , i need do display a field of type: boolean that is either true or false.

When I try to display it on the report , it's showing as true/false.

But, I would like to represent it as yes if value is true and no if false.

I think one way of doing is by changing the query that gets data to report.

But I would like to know, is there any way we can write that condition in the report itself 
to change representation.

Comment: Could you add a CASE statement to the dataset query at report level?

Comment: Probably i think yes..for now..i have used a kind of if in SSRS report itself..if we have multiple condidtions that we can go for switch case..Thanks for comments..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an expression field, add a textbox, right click => expression and use something like this: =IIF(Fields!LineTotal.Value = True, "This is true", "This is False")